# Android - Reading Character in a Text File

Tags: android

I want to read every character in a text file. For example I have a text file which contains the following text "John 26 Canada" and I want to read every Character so that I can put each String into its specific text view. This would be the output.

Name    : John
Age     : 26
Country : Canada

I have this code in saving data into text file.

```
private void performSaveFile(String f) {
    // this does the actual file saving.
    // set the filename in the interface:

    EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    EditText age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
    EditText country = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCountry);
    String strFileContent = name.getText().toString()
            + age.getText().toString() + country.getText().toString();

    // ... and save the file:
    try {
        FileOutputStream oStream = openFileOutput(f, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oStream.write(strFileContent.getBytes());
        oStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileOutputStream oStream = openFileOutput(f, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            oStream.write(strFileContent.getBytes());
            oStream.close();

above is your code , now you have taken f as string it should be File name.Code goes like this...

```
private void saveFromFile(String data) throws FileNotFoundException {

String FILENAME= "file.txt";

        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, this.MODE_PRIVATE);
         try {
              fos.write(data.getBytes());
              fos.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
              Log.e("Controller", e.getMessage() + e.getLocalizedMessage() + e.getCause());
        }
  }
```